# How do I see the differences between 2 MySQL dumps?

Tags: diff, mysql

I have 2 MySQL dump files. I want to find the table data difference between 2 tables.

Comment: This question desperately needs more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a DIFF tool - here are some graphical ones (both are free):

- [KDIFF](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
- [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Answer (score 20):

run mysqldump with "--skip-opt" to get the 2 dumps files i.e:

```
mysqldump --skip-opt -u $MY_USER -p$MY_PASS mydb1 > /tmp/dump1.sql

mysqldump --skip-opt -u $MY_USER -p$MY_PASS mydb2 > /tmp/dump2.sql
```

compare using these diff options:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines /tmp/dump1 /tmp/dump2
```

Comment: diff --normal --suppress-common-lines /tmp/dump1.sql /tmp/dump2.sql > difflines.sql
was better for me

Answer (score 6):

I just had to add lines breaks at `),(`'s so that each record becomes a separate line. Then the result can be fed to a tool like `diff`. This command does the job:

```sh
FORMAT_="s/),(/),\n(/g"
diff <(sed $FORMAT_ old-dump.sql) <(sed $FORMAT_ new-dump.sql)
```

Comment: I was in a situation where I couldn't easily re-run the dumps with additional arguments to shorten the lines, and this really increased readability of the diff. Then I used the solution from @vabada solution with git diff to highlight the diffs.

Comment: I added a second sed to handle the first table-entry:
`SED2="s/INSERT INTO \(.*\) VALUES [(]/INSERT INTO \1 VALUES\n(/g"`

Answer (score 4):

This tool is **not available** anymore, as the website is no longer functional.

Maybe you can give a tool called mysqldiff a go, I haven't tried it myself yet but it's been on my list for a while.

- <strike>http://www.mysqldiff.org/</strike>

Comment: As far as I understand, mysqldiff is about differences in table structure, not about differences in the data itself. This may or may not be what Tree is looking for...

Comment: blech,  a set of PHP scripts which requires a webgui, blah blah.

Answer (score 4):

This was very useful for me, so adding my two cents:

```
git diff --word-diff=color dump1.sql dump2.sql | less -R
```

Comment: Good tip.  Made it much easier to read the diffs.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I use. It works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Do a mysqldump of the a db, once a day or so and diff to the previous day. I want to catch when data has changed
# Use the --extended-insert=false so that each row of data is on a single line, that way the diff catches individual record changes

mv /tmp/dbdump0.sql /tmp/dbdump1.sql 2>/dev/null

mysqldump -h dbhostname.com -P 3306 -u username -p password --complete-insert --extended-insert=false dbname > /tmp/dbdump0.sql

# Ignore everything except data lines
grep "^INSERT" /tmp/dbdump0.sql  > /tmp/dbdump0inserts
grep "^INSERT" /tmp/dbdump1.sql  > /tmp/dbdump1inserts

diff /tmp/dbdump1.sql  /tmp/dbdump0.sql   > /tmp/dbdumpdiffs
r=$?
if [[ 0 != "$r" ]] ; then
    # notifier code remove
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to compare 2 mysql diffs they need to be done in a certain manner, so that the order is in a defined way and non relevant data is omitted.

This was at one point not totally possible with `mysqldump`, I am not sure if this has changed in the meantime.

One good tool for the job is `pydumpy` https://code.google.com/p/pydumpy/ (mirror: https://github.com/miebach/pydumpy)

If you want to compare to an old dump, like in the question, you could first create a temporary database from the dump and then start there.