# How do I verify a MySQL copy?

Tags: php, mysql

I have successfully copied several fields from table `foo` to table `bar`. Now before I delete the original record, I want to verify that it was all copied over correctly.

I tried using two identical SQL queries, assigning them to variables, and then comparing the variables with a comparison operator (tried both == and ===), like this:

```
$sqlFoo = "SELECT `value` FROM `foo` WHERE `user` = '000';";
$sqlBar = "SELECT `value` FROM `bar` WHERE `user` = '000';";

$resultFoo = $db->query($sqlFoo);
$resultBar = $db->query($sqlBar);

If ($resultFoo == $resultBar) {
// Proceed
}
```

When this didn't work, I used var_dump on my variables and they both returned:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(16) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(16) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Obviously my way is not working. Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `===` operator.

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php):

> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical
>   if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

So that would return `false` in your case as they refer to different instances.

However, you can compare them using `==` and that gives you the result you need:

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared
>   in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they
>   have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same
>   class.

So in your case:

```
if ($sqlFoo_result_object === $sqlBar_result_object) {
  // Proceed
}
```

About the `==` operator not working in your case: You were comparing the query result objects and not the literal strings, right? If you were and the result is still false, you might need to fetch a row and compare the results of the row and not the mysqli result object.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the fact that I did compare the results instead of the actual queries, and that the operand in use when I did the var_dump was (==). I was afraid I might have to compare fetched rows. I will try this and let you know how it turns out. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @RodtheSunGod I am not familiar enough with the mysqli result object to be able to tell you if you can compare them easily, I almost never use mysqli to be honest :-)

Comment: Do you use PDO? If so, do you know of a way to accomplish this using that method? I haven't used PDO too much yet, but I am willing to give it a shot if it will help me get things done :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd forego programming it in PHP myself and would use mysqldump on both databases and then just diff those dumps.

e.g.:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --skip-opt db_name foo >/tmp/foo
$ mysqldump -u root -p --skip-opt db_name bar >/tmp/bar
$ diff /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

The above is obviously assuming you have a unix environment and you can access your database (using a user "root" in this case, but any user that has read access will do).

See also:
[How do I see the differences between 2 MySQL dumps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840908/how-do-i-see-the-differences-between-2-mysql-dumps)