# is it possible to find out the difference between two mysql dump files?

Tags: mysql

I need know all the changes that happen in the mysql database during a process. All changes are insert only. For that i dumped the database before and after using following command

```
> mysqldump -u root -p sgdatabase_310ec9ef0bcea1f9c677369ea973ab75 > AfteOpDb.sql
```

Is there a way to see all the insert happens in the database on table by table bases?

And i don't mean text compare tool, Something specific to db that shows the difference graphically would be very nice.

OS : Windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I see the differences between 2 MySQL dumps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840908/how-do-i-see-the-differences-between-2-mysql-dumps)

Comment: Why don't you just query the database, by selecting rows that are inserted between process start and end? Is that not what databases are for, to analyse, manipulate and structure data?

Comment: Yes @N.B., that is the first thing that came to my mind. But the number of relations in the database is just too many. querying them before and after the operation one by one does not seem efficient.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840951/4431820), you can use a DIFF tool. A couple that can be used and are free (again, suggested in the original post) are:

- [KDIFF](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
- [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)